# Unable to add new screen via screen manager in kivy application

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to add the new connect screen. I am using screen manager.
I also updated the kv file. I was able to run the app with one screen, when I added new screen, I am getting the below error :

```
raise FactoryException('Unknown class <%s>' % name)
 kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <ConnectScreen>
```

**Now My firstapp.kv is as below :**

```
...
#:import AboutScreen screens
#:import ContactScreen  screens

NavigationLayout:
    id: nav_layout
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
        NavigationDrawerToolbar:
            title: 'Menu'
        NavigationDrawerIconButton:
            icon: 'arrow-right-drop-circle'
            text: 'About Us'
            on_release: app.root.ids.scr_mngr.current = 'about'
        NavigationDrawerIconButton:
            icon: 'arrow-right-drop-circle'
            text: 'Connect Us'
            on_release: app.root.ids.scr_mngr.current = 'connect'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Toolbar:
            id: toolbar
            title: 'Main Dashboard'
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            background_palette: 'Primary'
            background_hue: '500'
            left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: app.root.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
        ScreenManager:
            id: scr_mngr
            AboutScreen:
            ConnectScreen:
```

Now I have also updated the Builder.load.string
my **connect.py** is as below :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

Builder.load.string("""
<AboutScreen>
    name: 'connect'
    ScrollView:
        id: scroll
        do_scroll_x: False
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(800)
            padding: dp(15)
            spacing: dp(15)
            Image:
                source: './img/connect.jpeg'
                allow_stretch: True
""")


class ConnectScreen(Screen):
    pass
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: So you have .kv file and you put some kv code in .py files also? Why? I think the problem is that you add screens to screen manager and it requires name of the screens. Which you define in different file. Put all kv code in .kv file maybe that'll help.

Comment: thanks for your reply, answer mentioned below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

My **__init__.py** ( in screens folder) was not updated.

After I updated my **__init__.py**, it worked.

```
from .contact import ContactScreen
```

Comment: Looks like this answer can be self-accepted. It is not mandatory, but it helps keep things tidied up.